# Trying to figure out the structure of an input file based on a code

Tags: input, fortran

I'm sort of troubleshooting a code written in Fortran but I'm not yet familiar with it. I have the following code (a part), and basically, I have to 'reverse-engineer' the structure of the input file.

```
OPEN(10, FILE=TRIM(10)//'.txt', STATUS='OLD')
READ(10, *)     ! header

READ(10, *) NB_TEMP
ALLOCATE(TEMP(abs(NB_TEMP)))

IF (NB_TEMP <0) THEN
  NB_TEMP = ABS(NB_TEMP)
  READ(10, *) TEMP_0, TEMP_D
  TEMP(1) = TEMP_0
  DO I=2, NB_TEMP
    TEMP(I) = TEMP(I-1) + TEMP_D
  ENDDO
ELSEIF (NB_TEMP>0) THEN
  READ(10,*) TEMP(:)
ENDIF

READ(10, *) NB_PRS
ALLOCATE(PRS(ABS(NB_PRS)))
IF (NB_PRS<0) THEN
  NB_PRS = ABS(NB_PRS)
  READ(10, *) PRS_0, PRS_D
  PRS(1) = PRS_0*PI/180.
  DO I=2, NB_PRS
    PRS(I) = PRS(I-1) + PRS_D*PI/180.
  ENDDO
ELSEIF(NB_PRS>0) THEN
  READ(10,*) PRS(:)
  DO I=1, NB_PRS
    PRS(I) = PRS(I)*PI/180.
  ENDDO
ENDIF
```

So, I know I'm opening the .txt file first. Then, the first value I read is the "`NB_TEMP`*".* I'm not understanding what is happening at the second `READ` command. Does the program read the same values but set them differently, as "`NB_PRS`*"* I don't really have an error or anything - I'm simply trying to understand what this code does line-by-line and what would the structure be like for the input text file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fortran I/O is by default record based - you can think of a record as a line. So the first read reads data from the first line, and when finished moves to the start of the second line. The second read reads data on the second line, and the moves to the start of the third line. And so on.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You're totally right, I had changed the filename to a "10" just within this code, just as a unit number. The actual code has the file name identifier here instead of 10.

Comment: @IanBush: Thank you. But doesn't the line `READ(10,*) TEMP(:)` reads everything that precedes? If that happens, what would the line `READ(10,*) PRS(:)` do? I'm sorry if the questions are too simple or silly.

Comment: AHH, sorry, I over simplified. If you read multiple items and there are more than in the current record it will automatically move into the next and keep reading, as many times as required. But otherwise each read starts at the beginning of the next record, and you work your way down the file. So you read all of temp(:), nice to the start of the next record, and then read all of PRS(:)

Comment: Best way to understand it is create a file with a known structure and write a program to read it. Then alter the structure and try again. You learn programming by doing

Comment: It is important to know that implicitly `NB_TEMP` is of integer type. All variables that start with either of `IJKLMN` are assumed to be integers, and all others to be `real`. I would start by explicitly defining the types first and see if the code compiles and runs the same. it would be helpful if you can keep a baseline output and compare the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each read command reads a line from the file. Lets us examine them one by one

1. `READ(10, *)     ! header`

   Ignore the first line
2. `READ(10, *) NB_TEMP`

   Read an `integer` value into `NB_TEMP`.
3. `READ(10, *) TEMP_0, TEMP_D`

   Read two `real` values. This happens if `NB_TEMP` is negative, and they represent the starting value and the step for an arithmetic sequence stored into `TEMP(:)`. This is asserted from  `TEMP(I) = TEMP(I-1) + TEMP_D`.
4. `READ(10,*) TEMP(:)`

   Read multiple real values and store them into `TEMP(:)` array. The should be `NB_TEMP` count values in one line here.

and similarly for `PRS` where the program branches depending if the integer `NB_PRS` is positive or negative.

---

Here are some valid inputs they way I interpret this code

```
! TEST INPUT #1, DEFINED TEMP and PRS
6
    32.0000    40.0000    60.0000    90.0000    120.0000    130.0000    
9
    0.00000     5.0000     15.0000        20.0000     25.0000     30.0000     45.0000     55.0000     60.0000
```

```
! TEST INPUT #2, SEQUENCE TEMP and  DEFINED PRS
-6
    30.0000    10.0000
9
    0.00000     5.0000     15.0000        20.0000     25.0000     30.0000     45.0000     55.0000     60.0000
```

Comment: Thank you, this really clarifies things.